# How to apply time transformation to a factor variable in cph( ) function

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, rms

Hi I'm currently trying to fit a cox regression model but when I run the cox.zph() function, my p value is constantly smaller than 0.05 with the Delay variable being a major issue. It is a binary factor variable (0 or 1) describing whether a patient had early (0) or delayed (1) treatment. So from what I read on how to deal with this issue I tried to apply the tt() function to the Delay variable as such:

```
cox.death <- cph(Surv(diff, event)~tt(Delay)+rcs(age,3)+female+rcs(hba1c,3)+rcs(bmi,3)+rcs(egfr,3)+rcs(sbp,3),
                   data=cox.model, x = T, y = T)
```

But then I get this error message: `Error in tt(Delay) : could not find function "tt"`
I'm not quite familiar with the rms package but is there any solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: `cph` is from the  `rms` package. The `tt` function is designed to be used by `coxph` from the `survival` package.

Comment: Is there any equivalent in the ```rms``` package that can be used/recognized by ```cph()```

Comment: I really do not know. I wondered if the code for `tt` could just be copied over, but it clearly requires C code. See: http://mtweb.cs.ucl.ac.uk/mus/lib64/R/library/survival/doc/sourcecode.pdf. What I have not seen yet is either a reproducible example or an effort to load teh survival package.

Comment: I might further add that this might be  an X/Y question, i.e. how to do this with X when the real question is how should I be dealing with Y. I say this despite having used rms/Hmisc for many projects with great succes, but also with enourmous respect for Terry Therneau's work, especially his text with Patricia Grambsch: https://www.amazon.com/Modeling-Survival-Data-Extending-Statistics/dp/1441931619